# Read excel file with unicode name using openpyxl Python

Tags: python, excel, unicode

I am trying to read a file using openpyxl:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
some_excel = load_workbook('007РегистърСПО 2015.xls')
```

But it cannot be read properly. I am using Python 3 and openpyxl. Here's the error I am getting:

```
openpyxl.shared.exc.InvalidFileException: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '007??????????? 2015.xls'
```

Comment: try to include `u` next to file name to make it unicode...`u'007РегистърСПО 2015.xls`

Comment: What is your source file encoding? Have you tried converting to UTF-8 and adding `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` below `#!` line?

Comment: It seems to be also the space character in the filename...try to remove it and see if it helps...

Comment: I renamed the file to "input.xls", but now it gives the following error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Openpyxl only opens `.xlsx` (XML format) files.

Answer (score 1):

try to rename your file to english name

like '007РегистърСПО 2015.xls' => 'myfile.xls'

and use `load_workbook(filename='myfile.xls')`

Comment: What if I cannot do this? Isn't there a way to read unicode names?